# Is there an equivalent in Javascript for the C# Unspecified DateTime.Kind?

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

In C# we have the following DateTime.Kind:

```
Local
Utc
Unspecified
```

In Javascript, I have only seen Local and UTC. Is there an Unspecified one? If not, is it possible to recreate it?

Comment: it only really has UTC, and ways to convert it to local time according to the browser

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone

Comment: Recreate it how? What operation are you trying to perform? Unspecified isn't really "a thing" like Local and Utc are, it just affects conversions in the sense of "if kind is unspecified, and I'm performing conversion X, assume the time is the other one" so when you perform a "to local" on an unspecified, it assumes "developer implies time is utc, add offset"

Comment: @KeithNicholas—more accurate to say "…convert to local based on system settings or IANA representative location with [*toLocaleString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) or [*Intl.DateTimeFormat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) and the *timezone* option".